# Using Dropzone with .Net Master Pages and User Controls

Tags: javascript, .net, master-pages, dropzone.js, webusercontrol

I added the code as per the code in another answer (see below) and Page_Load is hit in the .cs when the files have uploaded, but Request.Files.Count is always 0.

The code works fine when you have a FORM tag, but not when it's using a masterpage or user control.

Am I missing something out?

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
        paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
        maxFilesize: 2, // MB
        url: "/dropzone.aspx?tid=<%=Request.QueryString["tid"]%>"
    };
</script>

<div id="my-awesome-dropzone" class="dropzone">
    <div class="fallback">
        <input name="file" type="file" multiple="multiple" runat="server" />
        <input name="btnUpload" type="submit" /><br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblFallbackMessage" runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create dropzone programmatically
 - http://www.dropzonejs.com/#create-dropzones-programmatically

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myId", { url: "/file/post"});
```